# How to solve the following nonlinear partial differential equation ?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Let we have the following nonlinear partial differential equation 
$$u+\frac{c^2}{x}\partial_xu(\partial_tu)^2=0$$ where $u=u(x,t)$ , $c>0$ a constant , $t>0$ and $c>x>0$ .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In these types of questions, I always find that making a reasonable ansatz can help guide you toward a solution. We can write the PDE as

$$u_{t}^{2} u_{x} = \frac{-x u}{c^{2}}$$

Now, in a *very* (**very !**) loose way, this looks somewhat like an eigenvalue problem in $x$. Hence, it makes sense to ansatz a solution of the form $u = g(t) e^{f(x)}$. Doing this turns our PDE into

$$(g' e^{f})^{2} \cdot g f' e^{f} = \frac{-x g e^{f}}{c^{2}}$$

Assuming $g \ne 0$, this gives us

\begin{align}
(g' e^{f})^{2} \cdot f' &= \frac{-x}{c^{2}} \\
\implies g'^{2} \cdot 2f'e^{2f} &= \frac{-2x}{c^{2}} \\
\implies (g')^{2} \cdot (e^{2f}) ' &= \frac{-2x}{c^{2}}
\end{align}

As $g'^{2} \ge 0$, we solve

$$g'^{2} = \frac{1}{c^{2}} \implies g = \pm \frac{t}{c} + k_{1}$$

and solving for $f$ yields

$$(e^{2f})' = -2x \implies f = \ln[(k_{2} - x^{2})^{1/2}]$$

where both $k_{1}, k_{2}$ are constants. Hence, **a** general solution to the PDE is given by

$$u = (k_{2} - x^{2})^{1/2} \left( \pm \frac{t}{c} + k_{1} \right)$$

Note that the solution method above is essentially just a separation of variables with the ansatz taking a particular form. Making a more general ansatz $u = f(x)g(t)$ yields the final solution

$$u = \pm \left( k_{2} - \frac{x^{2}}{\lambda} \right)^{1/2} \cdot \left( \pm \frac{\sqrt{\lambda} t}{c} + k_{1} \right)$$

where $\lambda$ is our separation constant.